# How to create a service account with no permissions in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a `serviceaccount` in Kubernetes with no permissions.

However, creating a new `serviceaccount` as follows results in a privileged `serviceaccount`, `sa`, that is able to e.g. retrieve pod information:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount sa -n devns

nlykkei:~/projects/k8s-examples$ kubectl get pods --as=system:serviceaccount:devns:sa -v6
I0318 16:12:34.161300    3466 loader.go:359] Config loaded from file:  /Users/nlykkei/.kube/config
I0318 16:12:34.179023    3466 round_trippers.go:438] GET https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods?limit=500 200 OK in 11 milliseconds
I0318 16:12:34.179299    3466 get.go:564] no kind "Table" is registered for version "meta.k8s.io/v1beta1" in scheme "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/api/legacyscheme/scheme.go:30"
No resources found.

nlykkei:~/projects/k8s-examples$ kubectl auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:devns:sa
Resources                                       Non-Resource URLs   Resource Names   Verbs
*.*                                             []                  []               [*]
                                                [*]                 []               [*]
selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io   []                  []               [create]
selfsubjectrulesreviews.authorization.k8s.io    []                  []               [create]
                                                [/api/*]            []               [get]
                                                [/api]              []               [get]
                                                [/apis/*]           []               [get]
                                                [/apis]             []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]          []               [get]
                                                [/healthz]          []               [get]
                                                [/openapi/*]        []               [get]
                                                [/openapi]          []               [get]
                                                [/version/]         []               [get]
                                                [/version/]         []               [get]
                                                [/version]          []               [get]
                                                [/version]          []               [get]
```

How can I create a `serviceaccount` with no permissions initially?

Comment: do you have an webhook or oauth provider configured for the Kubernetes cluster?

Comment: No, but `devns` is a namespace I created using `kubectl create namespace ...` - could that be the reason?

Comment: any role or rolebinding exists in the namespace devns?

Comment: No it’s a fresh namespace I just created

Comment: Is this in minikube or somewhere else that has rbac disabled?

Comment: @coderanger - it’s in Docker Desktop for Mac

Answer (score 1):

DfM Kubernetes injects a ClusterRoleBinding called docker-for-desktop-binding which does indeed give all perms to everything.

Comment: Can you say what’s the reason why such binding exists?

Comment: I checked the binding, it refers to the `namespace: kube-system`, so I guess your answer is wrong?

Comment: Check for other, similar bindings. It looks like the docker-for-desktop-binding was only switched to target kube-system fairly recently https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/3694#issuecomment-518557271